# Windows and Linux Containers simultaneously Windows 10

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-for-windows

I have a solution that includes about 5 containers. Most of them are alpine linux based, but one has to be a windows container. Unfortunately, the windows container relies on one of the linux containers for authentication and must be able to run alongside it. I am trying to set things up so I can develop locally with both containers running at the same time but I am having some trouble. Is it possible to run both Windows and Linux containers simultaneously on a Windows 10 Pro host using Docker for Windows (Hyper-V version)?

Essentially what I am looking for is the equivalent of running a docker compose file with both linux and windows containers in it (although everything I have researched says this isn't possible).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like docker edge version 18.02 has the ability to run windows and linux containers next to each other using LCOW (Linux Containers on Windows). It hasn't made it into docker-compose yet, but I think it will very soon. Can't wait for the stable version to have this!